# Importing child component only showing Frontend in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have a Citizenship component that I want to bring into my parent component App.js. To do this, I use `import Citizenship from './citizenship'` and add it in my default export, but this only shows all the front end components of my citizenship.js component and none of my backend api calls are being shown.

citizenship.js:

```
export default function Citizenship({ posts }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{textAlign:"center", marginTop:"20px", fontSize:"25px", color:"#0E2043", fontWeight: "500"}}>CITIZENSHIP</div>
        <div class="flexbox-container" style={{margin:"70px", marginTop:"0px"}}>
        {
          posts &&
          posts.map((post) => (
            <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>

          <div class="citizen-item" key={post.id}>
          {console.log(post)}          
            <div className="container6">
              <img
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", minHeight:"180px" }}
                src={`http://localhost:1337${post.Thumbnail.url}`}
              />
          </div>
        </div>        
        ))}
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/citizenships');
  const posts = await res.json();  
  
  return {
    props: {posts},
  }
}
```

and my App.js:

```
import Citizenship from './citizenship'

export default function App({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Citizenship />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the getStaticProps() into App.js:

```
import Citizenship from './citizenship'

export default function App({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Citizenship posts={posts}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/citizenships');
  const posts = await res.json();  
  
  return {
    props: {posts},
  }
}
```

And then pass the props into the Citizenship Component:

```
<Citizenship posts={posts}/>
```

More Infos can be found in the Next.js Docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `React.useEffect` to get the posts when the components initializes and use `React.useState` to store the posts.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/citizenships');
    const posts = await res.json();

    return {
        props: {posts},
    }
}

export default function Citizenship( ) {


    const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        //Do stuff when the React component initializes

        setPosts(getStaticProps());


    }, [])


    return (
        <>
            <div style={{textAlign:"center", marginTop:"20px", fontSize:"25px", color:"#0E2043", fontWeight: "500"}}>CITIZENSHIP</div>
            <div class="flexbox-container" style={{margin:"70px", marginTop:"0px"}}>
                {
                    posts &&
                    posts.map((post) => (
                        <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>

                            <div class="citizen-item" key={post.id}>
                                {console.log(post)}
                                <div className="container6">
                                    <img
                                        style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", minHeight:"180px" }}
                                        src={`http://localhost:1337${post.Thumbnail.url}`}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                        )
                    )
                }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: it can work, yes. But  getstaticprops is a nextjs feature. In this example it would be called client side.